# Extraer elementos de un data frame en R

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos con algunas probabilidades, así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
~FV, ~HC, ~HT, ~JA, ~JN, ~JP, ~JU, ~LA, ~LC, ~LM, ~MG,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11) -> datos_de_user
```

Me gustaría recorrer cada fila y decir por ejemplo si el valor es mayor 0.10 o si esta dentro de ciertos valores (entre 0.10 y 0.30), entonces muestre la letra que aparece como encabezado (FV,HC,HT)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo: Tengo estas ordenes de venta y necesito saber para la orden PB4184 cual clave (AL, CA etc) tiene la condición.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo: Tengo estas ordenes de venta y necesito saber para la orden PB4184 cual clave (AL, CA etc) tiene la condición.

Comment: Una pregunta para aclarar tu pregunta ¿Qué debería mostrar si NO se cumple la condición? Debería 1) Dejar el número que estaba. 2) Poner un NA 3) Eliminar el registro. 4) Otra cosa. Alternativamente ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo "hecho a mano" del resultado que querrías obtener? Con eso sin dudas obtendrás una respuesta.

Comment: @mpaladino Me gustaría extraer esas probabilidades por fila y cada probabilidad asociada a el nombre de columna por ejemplo de la primera fila: poner la condición de que la probabilidad sea igual a 0.1 y el resultado sea: MG=0.1 y en caso de haber mas mostrarlos todos

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta agregando una solución a este nuevo problema. Me dices...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo buscas filtrar los elementos de cada columna que cumplen con determinada condición y luego presentar pares de columnas y valores que cumplen.

## Los datos

> No es buena práctica mostrar los datos de ejemplo como una imagen, ya que no podemos cargar directamente esos datos a R para validar una respuesta. Acá están los datos legibles en R (le pasé un OCR, puede tener errores)

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
~FV, ~HC, ~HT, ~JA, ~JN, ~JP, ~JU, ~LA, ~LC, ~LM, ~MG,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11) -> datos_de_user
```

## Procedimiento

Para obtener el resultado que buscas vamos a hacer tres pasos, usando las funciones de la librería `tidyverse` .

1. **Pasar tus datos "formato largo".** Hay ciertas operaciones que son mucho más fáciles de hacer sobre pares de clave-valor. El motivo es simpre: un data.frame tiene que ser rectangular, todas las columnas del mismo largo y las filas de igual largo. Al pasarlo a claves-valor no sacamos de encima esa restricción. Digamos que en la columna A tenés dos valores que pasan tu filtro, y en la columna B tenés 4. Con un data.frame de filas y columnas eso es un problema, porque tendrías que rellenar con dos NA en A para que el resultado tenga el mismo largo que B. Al usar clave-valor te olvidas de ese problema.
2. **Agrupar los datos.** Como pasamos a clave-valor ya no tenemos columnas que nos organicen los datos. Para poder trabajar dentro de lo que *eran* columnas tenemos que agruparlos. De este modo por cada categoría en la variable `clave` tenemos un grupo y las operaciones posteriores se hacen *para cada grupo*.
3. **Aplicar el filtro.** Filtramos los valores *de cada grupo* que cumplen con determinada condición.

## Solución

```
#library(tidyverse)           # Está más arriba, pero es necesario.

datos_de_user %>% 
  gather(clave, valor) %>%    # Paso a formato largo clave-valor
  group_by(clave) %>%         # Agrupo por claves.
  filter(valor > 0.01)        # Filtro los valores mayores a 0.1

# A tibble: 14 x 2
# Groups:   clave [2]
clave valor
<chr> <dbl>
1  HT     0.03
2  HT     0.02
3  HT     0.04
4  HT     0.03
5  HT     0.02
6  HT     0.03
7  HT     0.03
8  MG     0.1 
9  MG     0.11
10 MG     0.11
11 MG     0.11
12 MG     0.12
13 MG     0.1 
14 MG     0.11
```

Otro ejemplo con mejores nombres de columna.

```
datos_de_user %>% 
  gather(variable, probabilidad) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  filter(probabilidad > 0.01 & probabilidad < 0.1) #Uso & para más de una condición

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   variable [1]
variable probabilidad
<chr>           <dbl>
1 HT               0.03
2 HT               0.02
3 HT               0.04
4 HT               0.03
5 HT               0.02
6 HT               0.03
7 HT               0.03
```

## Actualización después de la aclaración

*Entiendo* que lo que te interesa es saber qué órdenes tienen columnas que cumplen con determinada condición.

En ese caso lo podrías hacer con una lógica similar a la del caso anterior, solo que deberías:

1. bloquear a la columna `orden` cuando pases a pares de claves-valor. De lo contrario esa columna también se haría par de claves-valor y no te serviría para agrupar después.
2. hacer un doble agrupamiento por `orden` y `clave`. De ese modo el filtro se aplicará sobre los valores, pero dentro de **cada** orden y **cada** clave.
3. ordenar la columna `orden` para que queden juntas las ordenes que tienen más de un elemento que cumple la condición.

> Nota2: estos son los resultados con los datos de test que nos compartiste. Con otros datos u otras condiciones deberías tener otros resultados, quizás solo una de las ordenes cumpla con la condición. De todos modos la lógica es la misma.

```
resultados <- datos_de_user %>%                        #Para asignarle un nombre al resultado. 
      mutate(orden = paste("PB", 4184:4190, sep = "")) %>% #Agrego unos números de orden
      gather(clave, valor, -orden) %>%                     #-orden para "bloquear" esa variable.
      group_by(orden, clave) %>%                           #doble agrupamiento, para conservar orden
      filter(valor > 0.01)  %>%                            #filtro por condición
      arrange(orden) %>%                                   #orden para que cada orden quede junta 
      select(-valor)                                       #saco la columna "valor"

resultados

# A tibble: 14 x 2
# Groups:   orden, clave [14]
orden  clave
<chr>  <chr>
1 PB4184 HT   
2 PB4184 MG   
3 PB4185 HT   
4 PB4185 MG   
5 PB4186 HT   
6 PB4186 MG   
7 PB4187 HT   
8 PB4187 MG   
9 PB4188 HT   
10 PB4188 MG   
11 PB4189 HT   
12 PB4189 MG   
13 PB4190 HT   
14 PB4190 MG
```

Comment: Publique una respuesta con mas o menos lo que necesito ver, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, yo la orden ya la tengo creada y es este no se puede cambiar ni volver a crear

Comment: @user84003, solo cree la columna para hacer la prueba. En tu caso usarías la columna que ya está creada, si se llama orden solo deberías eliminar la línea que que dice `mutate ...`. PD: Si subes una parte de tus datos como prueba puedo poner el código para tus datos.

Comment: ya lo probé y me salió bien, ahora como almaceno ese resultado en un data. frame???

Comment: Ya está en data.frame! Sólo deberías asignarle un nombre. Edito la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda la solución de @mpaladino usando `dplyr` es más elegante y sencilla, sin embargo también puede lograrse algo similar con R base. La idea es básicamente la misma:

- Convertimos el formato "ancho" a uno "largo"
- Luego simplemente filtramos los valores deseados

#### Solución:

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
    ~Orden, ~FV, ~HC, ~HT, ~JA, ~JN, ~JP, ~JU, ~LA, ~LC, ~LM, ~MG,
    'PB4184', 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
    'PB4185', 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
    'PB4186', 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
    'PB4187', 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11,
    'PB4188', 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12,
    'PB4189', 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
    'PB4190', 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11) -> datos_de_user


newdata <- reshape(data=datos_de_user, 
                   direction="long",
                   varying=list(2:12),
                   times=names(datos_de_user)[2:12],
                   timevar="Columna",
                   v.names="probabilidad"
)
newdata <- newdata[newdata$probabilidad > 0.02 & newdata$probabilidad <= 0.1,]    
newdata <- newdata[order(newdata$Orden),c(1,2,3)]
newdata
```

- Con `reshape()` modificamos el formato "ancho" original a uno "largo"
- Con `newdata[newdata$probabilidad > 0.02 & newdata$probabilidad <= 0.1,]` filtramos las probabilidades de acuerdo a algún criterio deseado
- Por último y como un detalle más, con `newdata[order(newdata$Orden),c(1,2,3)]` ordenamos todo por el número de fila original y reordenamos también las columnas

La única particularidad de esta solución es que conservamos el `Orden` que corresponde a cada fila:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Orden  Columna probabilidad
  <chr>  <chr>          <dbl>
1 PB4184 HT              0.03
2 PB4184 MG              0.1 
3 PB4186 HT              0.04
4 PB4187 HT              0.03
5 PB4189 HT              0.03
6 PB4189 MG              0.1 
7 PB4190 HT              0.03
```

Hay algunas filas/Orden que se repiten ya que hay más de una columna en la que se da la condición que estamos evaluando. La forma consistente de manejar estos casos es duplicar estas filas como hacemos en el ejemplo anterior, sin embargo, por tus comentarios buscas que cada fila sea única y las coincidencias se muestren de forma "horizontal", no es una forma cómoda de dejar los datos, pero puede ser práctica a la hora de visualizarlos, para hacer esto podemos ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
final <- aggregate( paste(Columna, probabilidad, sep='=') ~ Orden, newdata, c)
names(final)[2] <- 'probabilidad'
final

   Orden    probabilidad
1 PB4184 HT=0.03, MG=0.1
2 PB4186         HT=0.04
3 PB4187         HT=0.03
4 PB4189 HT=0.03, MG=0.1
5 PB4190         HT=0.03
```

Aquí vemos que solo nos quedamos con una única fila por `Orden` y una nueva columna `probabilidad` con los casos que han coincidido con el criterio anterior. En este caso la columna `probabilidad`es un vector de cadenas de tamaño variable.

Comment: Super la ayuda me sirvió mucho, sin embargo necesito que me salgan es por fila no por columna; ejemplo en la fila 3 con la condición que poner en el filtro me debería salir HT y MG así seguidas. ya que cada fila corresponde como a una orden de venta y necesito saber para cada orden de venta cual es su clave asociada (MG, HT, etc ).

Comment: Publique una respuesta con más o menos lo que necesito ver, mil gracias !

Comment: @user84003, he edita mi respuesta para que se acerque a lo que buscas.